# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) using "join" code

Tags: r, data-science

I have a dataset with 100000 rows where order_date shows the order date and user_id where shows the user's ID. I am trying to create a new variable that shows the user's total order within the same day. My data is like this:

```
order_date=structure(c(15587, 15647, 15734, 15560, 15599, 15778, 15708, 
15520, 15592, 15447, 15718, 15787, 15519, 15486, 15514, 15784, 
15619, 15705, 15552, 15734, 15493, 15661, 15563, 15600, 15790, 
15485, 15546, 15767, 15704, 15726), class = "Date") 

user_id=c(22607, 28275, 32238, 20202, 4391, 7983, 29590, 11820, 22956, 
3196, 31125, 11709, 6586, 2920, 9698, 36814, 6954, 30368, 19052, 
827, 6599, 517, 8761, 20174, 37367, 11647, 18764, 27271, 30302, 
14808)

daten = data.frame(order_date = order_date, user_id = user_id)
```

I am using this code:

```
daten<-join(daten, count(daten, c("order_date", "user_id")))
```

It creates a new variable called "freq" and it was working until today. Now it doesn't work and I am getting an error message like this:

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `c("order_date", "user_id")` must be length 100000 (the number of rows) or one, not 2

I checked the structure of both variables using `str` and it says both have 100000 rows.

Comment: What is `daten`?

Comment: My data frame's name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which `join` (`inner_join`) you intend to use but one thing certainly not correct in your code is about `count`.

`count(daten, c("order_date", "user_id"))` should be changed to:

```
count(daten, order_date, user_id)
```

Comment: And what if I would like to use the column names as a dynamic string argument?

Comment: @Jelena-bioinf Then you have choice to use `dplyr::group_by_at` or `dplyr::summarise_at` depending upon your need.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same error message with passing string arguments to `group_by` function a vector of string variables as an argument. Thus, also following clarifications by @MKR, I'll add the solution to my problem, that also seems to solve the problem of the initial question:

```
daten %>% 
group_by_at(vars(one_of(c("order_date", "user_id")))) %>% 
summarise(n = n())
```

With the original data, it doesn't make much sense (as all entries are unique in both columns), but in other cases, this might be useful

Comment: Good use of `one_of`. May be you can add a toy dataframe to highlight use of your solution.